# Address of global variable does not changes even after renaming the symbol

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I am trying to create copies of global variable, one copy per SO. For that I am renaming the global variable after compilation using `objcopy`. But I am not able to achieve desired result.

I have my `abc.c` as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int global_var = 0;                                                                                                                                                   

void xyz()
{    
    printf("%s:%d => %d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,global_var);
    ++global_var;
    printf("%s:%d => %d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,global_var);
    printf("%x\n",&global_var);
}
```

And `main1.c` as following:

```
void xyz();

void main_first()
{
    xyz();
}
```

And `main2.c` as following:

```
void xyz();

void main_2nd()
{
    xyz();
}
```

And `testing.c` as:

```
void main_first();
void main_2nd();

int main()
{
    main_first();
    main_2nd();
}
```

Finally my `CMakeLists.txt` is as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(sample_project)

set(CMAKE_OBJECT_COPY objcopy)

add_definitions(-fPIC)                                                                                                                                                

set(_tn libone.so)
add_library(one SHARED main1.c abc.c)
add_custom_command(TARGET one
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJECT_COPY} --redefine-sym _Z3xyzv=_Z7one_xyzv --redefine-sym _ZL10global_var=_ZL14one_global_var ${_tn})

set(_tn libtwo.so)
add_library(two SHARED main2.c abc.c)
add_custom_command(TARGET two
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJECT_COPY} --redefine-sym _Z3xyzv=_Z7two_xyzv --redefine-sym _ZL10global_var=_ZL14two_global_var ${_tn})

add_executable(sample test.c)

target_link_libraries(sample one two)
```

I am renaming both `xyz()` and `global_var` here. So, am expecting that both SOs will have different copies of `global_var`. But when I run that I get following output.

```
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc.c:8 => 0
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc.c:10 => 1
98eb5050
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc.c:8 => 1
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc.c:10 => 2
98eb5050
```

Which is contrary to the assumption. Address printed should have been different in both cases.

Which step is incorrect in this process?

Is it even possible to achieve this?

And yes `-fvisibility=hidden` has worked for me, is their any thing else I can do to achieve same?

Comment: Global variable receive a dedicated memory space - how can you duplicate it without giving a new memory address?

Comment: @dear_tzvi: I second you on that, and it is about visibility of that symbol. and that's why `-fvisibility=hidden` did the trick for me.

Comment: I did a rest, and the `redefine-symbol` doesn't seem to work reliable with `so` files at least. `objdump -R test.so` still did output the old name.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb,   what are my options then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach can be to build like following: (Localize the symbols)

```
gcc -c -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden abc.c -o abc.o
objcopy --keep-global-symbol=xyz abc.o

gcc -c -fPIC  main1.c -o main1.o
gcc -shared main1.o abc.o -o libone.so

gcc -c -fPIC  main2.c -o main2.o
gcc -shared main2.o abc.o -o libtwo.so

gcc test.c -L. -lone -ltwo
```

And output will be as:

```
abc.c:8 => 0
abc.c:10 => 1
666a0034
abc.c:8 => 0
abc.c:10 => 1
6649e034
```

Answer (score 1):

`objcopy --rename-symbol` doesnt't rename dynamic symbols. There's no option or utility for that. So it will work with static libraries or regular object files, but not dynamic libraries.

To verify, see the output of

```
   nm libone.so
   nm -D libone.so
```

before and after renaming.

You can rename the symbols at any stage orior to producing the final shared library.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @n.m.'s answer, I did following and it worked too.(Without changing source i.e. source files were same as in question).

```
gcc -c -fPIC abc.c -o abc1.o
objcopy --redefine-sym xyz=one_xyz --redefine-sym global_var=one_global_var abc1.o
gcc -c -fPIC main1.c -o main1.o
objcopy --redefine-sym xyz=one_xyz --redefine-sym global_var=one_global_var main1.o

gcc -shared main1.o abc1.o -o libone.so

gcc -c -fPIC abc.c -o abc2.o
objcopy --redefine-sym xyz=two_xyz --redefine-sym global_var=two_global_var abc2.o
gcc -c -fPIC main2.c -o main2.o
objcopy --redefine-sym xyz=two_xyz --redefine-sym global_var=two_global_var main2.o

gcc -shared main2.o abc2.o -o libtwo.so

gcc test.c -L. -lone -ltwo
```

And output was:

```
abc.c:8 => 0
abc.c:10 => 1
e10003c
abc.c:8 => 0
abc.c:10 => 1
defe03c
```

Answer (score -1):

I could achieve it. by changing `main1.c` as:

```
void xyz();

__attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) void main_first()                                                                                                            
{
    xyz();
}
```

And `main2.c` as:

```
void xyz();

__attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) void main_2nd()                                                                                                              
{
    xyz();
}
```

And added `add_definitions(-fPIC -fvisibility=hidden)` in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)      

project(sample_project)                  

set(CMAKE_OBJECT_COPY objcopy)           

add_definitions(-fPIC -fvisibility=hidden)                                                                                                                            

add_library(one SHARED main1.c abc.c)    

add_library(two SHARED main2.c abc2.c)   

add_executable(sample test.c)            

target_link_libraries(sample one two)
```

And it worked.

```
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc.c:8 => 0
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc.c:10 => 1
69e93048
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc2.c:8 => 0
/home/gautam/cprog/sample_project/abc2.c:10 => 1
69c91048
```

Also one case use GCC pargma to achieve similar effect. Like...

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)

void main_first()
{
    xyz();
}

#pragma GCC visibilty pop
```